# open an application with in an application

Tags: android

I have an application and want to divide in two part one part contain some icon of different application on click of icon application launch on second pane.
Is this possible? if yes then how? and if no then what would best alternative for this
 please help me I am new in android. I would be highly obliged. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out for "implicit intents". It is exactly what you are looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you'll need to take a look at the [Interacting with Other Apps](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) part of the Android training section.